# Multiple RewriteRule being ignored

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to add another **RewriteRule** to my current .htaccess, Here's how the .htaccess currently appears

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10 

AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" html 
AddType "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" txt 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# if file not exists 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

# if dir not exists 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# avoid 404s of missing assets in our script 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC] 

# core framework url rewriting 
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

I then tried to add the following before the `RewriteRule .* index.php` yet it still gets completely ignored

```
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ /myAPI.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should keep your .htaccess with the new rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" html 
AddType "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" txt 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# API rule
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ /myAPI.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# if file not exists 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if dir not exists 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# avoid 404s of missing assets in our script 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC] 
# core framework url rewriting 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```